# Why do I get an error when I remove Chunksize?

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning

I'm encountering an error while running my Python code and need assistance in resolving it. Below are the details of the :

```
import pandas as pd

df_list = []
file_path = 'houses.txt'

for chunk in pd.read_csv(file_path, chunksize=1000000, names=['Size()sqft', 'No of bedrooms', 'No of floors', 'Age of home', 'Price(1000s dollar)']):
    df_list.append(chunk)

df = pd.concat(df_list)

print(df_list)
```

Output :

```
0        952.0             2.0           1.0         65.0                271.5
1       1244.0             3.0           1.0         64.0                300.0
2       1947.0             3.0           2.0         17.0                509.8
3       1725.0             3.0           2.0         42.0                394.0
4       1959.0             3.0           2.0         15.0                540.0
..         ...             ...           ...          ...                  ...
95      1224.0             2.0           2.0         12.0                329.0
96      1432.0             2.0           1.0         43.0                388.0
97      1660.0             3.0           2.0         19.0                390.0
98      1212.0             3.0           1.0         20.0                356.0
99      1050.0             2.0           1.0         65.0                257.8

[100 rows x 5 columns]]
```

After removing 'chunksize'. I get this error:

`TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

Kindly explain what's the issue

Comment: Have you looked with `df_list` is before you try to `pd.concat` it? have you done *any* debugging at all?

Comment: I am a bit new in pandas. If u want to recommend any source to make my pandas better, feel free to help 

Answer (score 1):

`chunksize` [implies `iterable`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#iterator) and is what changes the return type of `read_csv` to be a `TextFileReader` object that you're iterating over.

> chunksize : int, optional
> Number of lines to read from the file per chunk. Passing a value will cause the function to return a `TextFileReader` object for iteration. See the [IO Tools docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) for more information on `iterator` and `chunksize`.

When `chunksize` is not specified, it returns a `DataFrame` instead.

So, if you remove `chunksize`, `iterable` is no longer implied, and the object that you end up iterating over in your `for` loop will be no longer be a `TextFileReader` object, and the object types in your `df_list` will also be different as a consequence, ultimately causing the error when you call `pd.concat` on that list.

Chunking the file is useful in some cases where responsiveness or memory are concerns or when the full df is not needed, but if you don't need to chunk the file and want the full dataframe anyhow, you can skip the iteration and subsequent concatenation and just read the whole file into a dataframe in one step:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, names=['Size()sqft', 'No of bedrooms', 'No of floors', 'Age of home', 'Price(1000s dollar)'])
```